# Efficient approximation of a matrix and its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, approximation-theory

Assume that $ A $ is a real $ n\times n $ matrix whose rows constitute an orthonormal basis of $ \mathbb R^n $.

**Informal statement of question:** Assume we want to approximate $ A $ by a rational matrix, such that each entry can be written efficiently (that is, has a small binary encoding), but we require also the inverse of the approximate matrix to have small representation. Is this possible?

**Formal statement of question:** Let $ p(n) $ be some polynomial in $ n $. For a real number $ r $, we say that $ a/b $ is a *polynomial approximation of $ r $*, if $ a/b$ is a rational number (that is, $ a,b $ are integers) and both $ a $ and $ b $ are of size at most  $p(n) $ (e.g., their binary representation is of logarithmic size in $ n $), such that $ |r-a/b|\le 1/p(n) $.

*Question*: Does there exist a rational matrix $ B$, such that $ B $ polynomially approximates $ A $ (that is, the entry $ B_{ij} $ in $ B $, is a polynomial approximation of the entry $ A_{ij} $ in $ A $, for all $ 1\le i,j\le n $), and such that $ B^{-1} $ is a rational matrix whose entries are all polynomially-bounded (that is, for any $ 1\le i,j\le n $, $ B^{-1}_{ij}=a/b$, where $ a,b $ are integers of size at most $ p(n) $) ?

Answer (score 4):

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, [Milenkovic and Milenkovic](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.52.4964) give an alogrithm for efficiently approximating an orthogonal matrix by a rational orthogonal matrix. As lhf points out, the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is its transpose, so the inverse will also have short entries in this setting.

Regarding $n>3$, here is a tentative thought, and a reference. I haven't put much effort into either :).

Let $v=(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)$ be a nonzero vector. Define a linear operator 
$$s_v(u) := u - 2 \frac{\langle v,u \rangle}{\langle v,v \rangle} v.$$
This is the orthogonal reflection that negates $v$. Note that, if $v \in \mathbb{Q}^n$, then the entries of the matrix $s_v$ are rational. This is true even if $v$ does not have norm $1$.

Now, any rotation matrix can be written as a product of $\leq n$ reflections: $R=\prod_{i=1}^h s_{v_i}$ for some sequence of vectors $v_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. A potential algorithm, then, is to find such a factorization and then approximate each $v_i$ by a rational vector $w_i$ which is roughly parallel to it. (There are plenty of standard algorithms for rational approximation of a vector.) Then take $\prod s_{w_i}$ as the approximation to $R$.

I got this strategy from a paper of [Eric Schmutz](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2425007). Schmutz follows this strategy, but he forces his approximating vectors $w_i$ to lie on the unit sphere. As far as I can see, this is a waste of effort, since $s_v$ is orthogonal with rational entries even if $v$ is not on the unit sphere. However, Schmutz has exact bounds, which you may find useful.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. Maybe they (or future citations of this paper) have some references for the general case of $ n $.

Comment: I haven't followed through on the links, so I don't know which method do they use, but my first reaction to "rational orthogonal matrix" is "Cayley transform". 

Answer (score 3):

If *A* is orthogonal then its inverse is the transpose and so you only need to approximate *A*.

Comment: But your approximation may not be orthogonal, so its inverse may require a lot of bits to store. 

Comment: Yes, David is right.
(lhf would be right too, if the orthogonalization algorithm (of e.g., Gram-Schmidt) would end up with a matrix in which the entries are polynomially-bounded by the entries in the original matrix. I can't see why this should be true though.)